# PHP-FPM Upgrade Problems

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, configuration, php-fpm, ubuntu-20.04

We've recently upgraded to PHP-FPM from CGI. We're having issues on a Ubuntu server which just runs Apache and PHP-FPM controlling 5 or so sites. We've built a new server with a fresh install of Ubuntu to do this.

Our problem is that at intervals through the night our site becomes unavailable and CPU usage on the server spikes to 90% when we get increased traffic to our API. This didn't happen on the old server running CGI so I suspect it is a PHP-FPM configuration problem.

So we need a bit of guidance on where we've gone wrong. I'll put the .conf settings below:

Apache MPM_EVENT Settings:

```
ServerLimit     1187
StartServers            4
MinSpareThreads      25
MaxSpareThreads      75
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxRequestWorkers     1175
MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
```

PHP-FPM www.Conf:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 60
pm.max_requests = 500
request_terminate_timeout = 5m
```

Virtual Server Specs:

```
Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS
8GB RAM
Intel Xeon Silver 4110 2.1Ghz 4 cores
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated, thank you.